# I want to delete a row on tableview , but I'm receiving an error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        task.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: cell, with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

the error is

> Cannot convert value of type 'TaskCell' to expected argument type '[IndexPath]'

Comment: Never call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: And – as always – `beginUpdates / endUpdates` is pointless for a ***single*** `insert/delete/move` operation.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `cell` instead of `indexPath` to the `deleteRows` function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        task.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: for completeness, that `cell` constant is redundant after fixing the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `[IndexPath]` in place of `cell` in your code.

Replace below in your code with

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: cell, with: .automatic)
```

with

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you can add this extension for tableview and than delete row than after you need to reload the tableview data like below,**

```
extension UITableView {
func reloadDataAfterDelay(delayTime: TimeInterval = 0.4) -> Void {
    self.perform(#selector(self.reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: delayTime)
}
}
```

**the tableview rowaction look like this.**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let repo = numberofrecord[indexPath.row]as! [String] // your datasource

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: {
        act,del in

            let query = "delete from repost where id=\(repo[0])"; // delete the datasource from databases.
            let s = db.dml(query: query)
            if s == true {
                print("media delete")
            }
            else{
                print("not deleted");
            }

            self.numberofrecord.remove(at: indexPath.row) // delete datasource from array.

            self.tbl.beginUpdates()
            self.tbl.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) // delete row of table.
            self.tbl.endUpdates()

            self.tbl.reloadDataAfterDelay() // Reload the table after some delay.

    })

    return [delete]
}
```

this is the proper and perfectly work in swift.